# Error opening Android database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on creating an Android application. I put a button to create database and when i try to press in the same button the second time to open the database there is an error

> "failure 1 (table List is already exist)"

that's the code of button:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try{
                    SQLiteDatabase ldb = openOrCreateDatabase(dbName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                    ldb.execSQL(TableStructure);
                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                    cv.put("task", text);
                    cv.put("checkbox", 1);
                    ldb.insert(tableName, null, cv);
                    ldb.close();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(List.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                    Intent in = new Intent(List.this, DsTest2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(in);

        }
```

Comment: What's your question? The reason you get an error is because the database/table indeed already exists... If you don't want the error, change your query to 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS'

Answer (score 1):

You didn't put the whole code, but I assume `TableStructure` is a `String` with an SQL sentence to create the tables. As the error is already telling you:

```
table List already exists
```

the tables are already created by a previous execution of this method.

You first need to check if the DB is already created and execute the creation SQL sentence only if not created. Or as *user1810737* correctly suggests, use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` instead of plain `CREATE TABLE`

Comment: when i press the button in my first time button create the database but when i press the button in next time when i open project again the error is shown

Comment: That's what I said: "the tables are already created by a previous execution of this method"

Comment: ok i want when the i press button again open the table and put new information on it

Comment: Your question was about why it gives the error, not this. This is not a forum. Make a new question for your new problem, but first try to solve it yourself.